# facebook getloginurl authentication permissions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

seems having updated to the latest version of the facebook php sdk the following code is not working-

```
$loginUrl   =   $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
           'canvas'    => 0,
           'fbconnect' => 1,
           'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,status_update,offline_access'
           ));
```

the user is not being asked for the extended permissions- some digging has come up with fb now requesting you add these permissions in the facbeook developer app- under Authenticated Referrals- i added them in and still nothing

anyone any ideas- without being able to post when a user completes an action my app is useless and am out of a job

update-

the new sdk requires different params-

```
$loginUrl   =   $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream,status_update,offline_access'));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Connect Question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5444637/facebook-connect-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, the new oauth2 requires you to define the requested permissions in the scope parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
$loginUrl   =   $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
           'canvas'    => 0,
           'fbconnect' => 1,
           'scope' => 'publish_stream,status_update,offline_access'
           ));
```

**req_perms** key changed to **scope**